# Strange shadows in interior scene

Tags: modeling

With massive help of Blender Guru I am making my first interior scene. At about 42:30 min in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4G9cMi8QAa4) he makes a render:

[image]

and my render looks like this. What are these very deep shadows on the pillars of the couch ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe the hdr in your World Properties is not the same (free version vs pro?) or the Multiply and Add Nodes need a little tweaking or the Mapping needs a bit of adjustment

Comment: The Average Node in the leather material is causing the broad stripes in the couch.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. I just appended the couch from the tutorial's blend files and did not change a thing. When I change this Vector Math node from "average" to "normalize" everything seems to work but no idea wath this node does ??

Comment: @OldMan, for information, I have reloaded the pillows from "Couch - Leather brown.blend" of the starter pack into your "modern interior" file and the problem disapeared... but I was not able to find why.